# What are the differences between "Crawling peg" and "Crawl-like arrangement"?

Tags: international-economics, definition, imf

The [IMF AREAER 2019](https://www.elibrary-areaer.imf.org/Pages/Home.aspx) classifies 3 countries as "crawling" and 18 as "crawl-like". It's not clear to me though how these classifications were made and why they couldn't be switched around. For example, why is Botswana "crawling" while Burundi is "crawl-like"?

"Crawling peg":

> Classification as a crawling peg involves the confirmation of the country authorities’ de jure exchange rate arrangement. The currency is adjusted in small amounts at a fixed rate or in response to changes in selected quantitative indicators, such as past inflation differentials vis-à-vis major trading partners or differentials between the inflation target and expected inflation in major trading partners. The rate of crawl can be set to generate inflation-adjusted changes in the exchange rate (backward looking) or set at a predetermined fixed rate and/or below the projected inflation differentials (forward looking). The rules and parameters of the arrangement are public or notified to the IMF.

"Crawl-like arrangement":

> For classification as a crawl-like arrangement, the exchange rate must remain within a narrow margin of 2% relative to a statistically identified trend for six months or more (with the exception of a specified number of outliers) and the exchange rate arrangement cannot be considered as floating. Normally, a minimum rate of change greater than allowed under a stabilized (peg-like) arrangement is required. However, an arrangement will be considered crawl-like with an annualized rate of change of at least 1%, provided that the exchange rate appreciates or depreciates in a sufficiently monotonic and continuous manner.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already in your question. As the IMF paper says:

> Classification as a crawling peg involves the confirmation of the country authorities’ de jure exchange rate arrangement.

So the difference between crawling peg and crawling-like is that in the first case country officially states that it is doing crawling peg, while with the crawling-like arrangement the country does not officially follow crawling peg, but behaves in a way as if it would be following it.